# Is there anyway to fix this? Unity materials with diagonal lines

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, textures

[do you see them?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HjTn.png)

I am pretty sure its something to do with shaders but I'm not too sure, is there anyway I can fix it? it doesn't get stretched with the object and I'm sure its something I did without realising in the project settings. please help.

Comment: looks like [shadow acne](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/q/2192/19942) to me

Answer (score 0):

It's [shadow acne](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/2192/cause-of-shadow-acne). This answer explains it very well, but the solution is to increase the [bias](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Light-shadowNormalBias.html) of your scene light.

[image: Light component]

There's no magic formula, just play with it until you get the desired effect. Be sure not to increase the bias too far, or you will get separation where shadows don't connect properly to the base of objects casting them. It's a trade-off unfortunately.

[Read more from unity here](https://docs.unity3d.com/550/Documentation/Manual/ShadowOverview.html).