What's going on with the lighting?
With the lighting on my HDRP stage, something is wrong with the lighting in some corners on the floor and on the walls.

I don't understand what this could be related to.
I also tried to place Light-Probes to solve this problem.
I've tried changing the lighting and materials settings.

Try this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/76204931/7711148

Jay, I don't think this will work, since I have HDRP installed and the settings are different from those written on this post.

I see, this is the same thing in HDRP. Try playing with this.
